# webBrowser check is jquery dialog box is active

Tags: c#, browser

is there any possible way to check is in webBrowser1 is any jquery dialog active?
here's how looks the dialog which i want to check
**i using c# webBrowser class, this is not in a simple html webpage**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this -

```
if($(".ui-dialog").is(":visible"))
{
//dialog is open
}
```

Comment: i using c#, this is not in web page!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$("#mydialog").dialog( "isOpen" )
```

Comment: i using c# and webbrowser class, this is not in a webpage

Comment: so why do you refer to jquery if not in html context?

Comment: i thought i should mention it, because i try to check jquery/js dialog